# Link within onclick div in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a div which has a link with onclick (see the code). Within this div there is another link which goes to another page than the whole div. This code as below works well in IE, Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. In Safari you still go the the whole div link instead of the other link. Any idea how to fix? I found some suggestions in other post, but until now nothing worked for me.

```
<div class="coach-list" style="cursor: pointer;"
     onclick="window.location='/page';if (!e) var e = window.event;
                                e.cancelBubble = true;
                                if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();">
    <div class="coach-list-inner">
        <h4>Name</h4>

        <p><a href="/otherpage" target="_blank">Link to other page</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `e.preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working exemple for me. Avoid using inline JS BTW.

```
<div class="coach-list" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="coach-list-inner">
         <h4>Name</h4>

        <p><a href="/otherpage" target="_blank">Link to other page</a>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>

$('.coach-list').click(function () {
    alert('div');
    window.location = '/page';
    return true;
});

$('a').click(function (e) {
    alert('a');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @EricStack : Have you tried this solution? Please give us feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `e.stopPropagation();` with `return: false;`. Seems to work in Safari here:

```
window.location='/page';if (!e) var e = window.event;
                                e.cancelBubble = true;
                                return false;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/bmodwvzg/

`return: false;` is equal to `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();`.

https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/